# What is the best way to fetch memory usage of any website

Tags: php, linux, shell, memory, nginx

while working on a PHP script I needed to fetch the server memory usage Now here is the approach that I've taken to do that:

```
$a= function_exists('memory_get_usage') ? round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2) : 0;

$memory_consumption_percent = round ($a / $a * 100, 0);
```

But I realized that this is not the best way to do this because it only returns the amount of memory, in bytes, that's currently being allocated to your PHP script.

So, I contacted my friend who is much more experience in shell scripting to find out if there is any way to fetch this memory usage data which I can ten run though `shell_exec()`. But he said its impossible to do any kind of generic shell scripting which will run on any environment.

He said the way Apache, Lightspeed, lighthttpd, nginx handles PHP is different, so it's hard to write a script which will tell how much memory your site is consuming. Also if you just check for the free RAM or RAM usage on the server, then again it will be completely ambiguous as there are many things running on the server that consumes memory but that is not the memory consumption of your website.

Standing at this point I thought I should I ask you guys about this as you people has much more experience and may be help me to come up with a generic solution.

P.S.: I'm looking forward to only Linux server based solution.

Comment: You could probably get the process list, grep the webserver/php instances and then add them together.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that I've done it.  I did it this way because it reports on not just physical memory, but swap and buffers as well.

Start a `cron job` to run how ever often you want to update this info (every minute for instance)  The command for editing your `cron` is `sudo crontab -e`.  Inside you'll set something that looks like this:

```
* * * * * rm /path/to/your/log/file/memory.log; while true; do free -s 1 > /path/to/your/log/file/memory.log; sleep 1; done
```

Then you can access that log via your php file anytime you want ...  Using things like `strpos` etc you'll be able to extract the info you want from the log. This is how I did it, and it works excellently.

Comment: That's a great approach, but I cannot use it as it needs to be go inside a plugin that will be used in many different sites. So I cant just ask people to create that cron job.